# How can I repeat a picture in pictureBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox

The image has 200px width and the pictureBox has 400px.

Which property of pictureBox should I set to display the image repeat-x?

Comment: What is wrong with the default `BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Tile;` Please clarify exactly what you are trying to accomplish. You want to shrink the image and repeat it a number of times in the `PictureBox`?

Comment: @CodeCamper  yes, i want to repeat the image a number of times in picturebox but no need to shrink or scale it.

Comment: @Ice, so what happens when you use `ImageLayout.Tile`? Does it shrink and distort the image?

Comment: Maybe @Ice not talking about ImagebackGround .. but Image properties ..

Comment: @matzone is right. i didn't state it clearly. I'm asking about the Image properties!  thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any property which makes the image display x times repeatedly horizontally. But a little custom code can help, here is my code:

```
public static class PictureBoxExtension
{
    public static void SetImage(this PictureBox pic, Image image, int repeatX)
    {
        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(image.Width * repeatX, image.Height);
        Graphics gp = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
        for (int x = 0; x <= bm.Width - image.Width; x += image.Width)
        {
            gp.DrawImage(image, new Point(x, 0));
        }
        pic.Image = bm;
    }
}

//Now you can use the extension method SetImage to make the PictureBox display the image x-repeatedly 
myPictureBox.SetImage(myImage, 3);//repeat 3 images horizontally.
```

You can customize the code to make it repeat vertically or look like a check board.

Hope it helps!